# Fokker Plank equation and Markov processes with generator $L$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-process

Let $X_t$ a Markov process with generator $L$. Let $L^*$ be the adjoint of $L$.

Is it true that, by the Fokker Plank equations, I can conclude that, $u_t(x)$, probability density function of the process satisfies

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u_t(x)=L^*u_t(x)$$

Comment: Don't the Fokker Plank equations only apply to Itô processes? These are very particular Markov processes. Note that a general Markov process need not even *have* a transition density, only a transition kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the following doubt. A Markov process can completely be characterized by its generator. Therefore if I know the generator $L$ I should know everything about the process. How can I understand, looking at the generator, if the process has a probability density or not?

Comment: The question of existence of density is quite non-trivial. There are various sufficient conditions for different kinds of processes.

Comment: If I know that the process at time $0$ has a density $f(x)$ and I know that the equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u_t(x)=L^*u_t(x)$ with initial condition $u_0(x)=f(x)$ has a unique solution $u_t(x)$, is this sufficient to conclude that the solution $u_t(x)$ is the density of the process?